# Unknown "form" function php symfony/form twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony-forms, symfony5

In my project I have installed symfony / form, symfony / twig-bridge
but whenever I run the template does not recognize me the tags to render the forms that I could miss? both are in version 5, all the time show this , Unknown "form" function , Unknown "form_start" function

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;  
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;     
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class TaskController extends AbstractType
{
public function new()
{
    // creates a task object and initializes some data for this example       
    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();
    $form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Task'])
        ->getForm();

    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('vista/parte');
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, ['debug' => true]);                
    return $twig->render('foms.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);       
}
}

(new TaskController())->new();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few things here.

Controller and form types are two separate things. You can create your form in your controller, and then pass it to the view.

However if you want to separate your form from your controller, you can create a form type that will extend `AbstractType`

This should look like this:

```
class TaskController extends AbstractController // add the use for that one
{
    public function new()
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Task'])
            ->getForm();

        return $twig->render('foms.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);       
    }
}
```